# Stream api collectors grouping by zero counted fileds

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

I have an object has a filed type1 used to create first group and i have two fields are used to create second group. But second group always get one of theese three values (X,Y,Z). At this point i wrote a code like this :

```
Map<String, Map<String, Long>> result = objList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Obj::type1,
                     Collectors.groupingBy(Obj::useTwoFieldToGetSecondGroup, Collectors.counting())))
```

As result of this code i get this :

```
{
  "A":{
     "Y":5,
     "Z":3
  },
  "B":{
     "Y":2,
     "Z":1
  },
  "C":{
     "X":2
  },
  "D":{
     "X":6,
     "Z":2
  }
```

}

But i know second type has always three types of values and i want to see sth like this :

```
{
  "A":{
     "X":0,
     "Y":5,
     "Z":3
  },
  "B":{
     "X":0,
     "Y":2,
     "Z":1
  },
  "C":{
     "X":2,
     "Y":0,
     "Z":0
  },
  "D":{
     "X":6,
     "Y":0,
     "Z":2
  }
```

}

are there any vay to get this result easily?

```
public classObj {

   private String type1; //key of first map

   private String field1; //second key calculated with this two fields
   private String field2;

   public String useTwoFieldToGetSecondGroup(){
       //use field1 and field2 to get X or Y or Z
   }

}
```

and useTwoFieldToGetSecondGroup method like this:

```
private String useTwoFieldToGetSecondGroup() {
    if(field1 && field2){
        return "X";
    } else if(!field1 && field2){
        return "Y";
    } else {
        return "Z";
    }
}
```

Comment: yes for an object in the list useTwoObjectToGetSecondGroup method always return x or y or z(only one of them for an object). Because of X,Y,Z are enum types i cant add them in a class. i use two field and decide the value of second map key. i am editing the question.

Comment: result.values().forEach(x -> {
   if(!x.containsKey("X")) {
    x.put("X", 0L);
   }
   if(!x.containsKey("Y")) {
    x.put("Y", 0L);
   }
   if(!x.containsKey("Z")) {
    x.put("Z", 0L);
   }
  });

Comment: ha sorry yes you are right i will change it

Comment: sorry, i dont get it. can you illustrate

Comment: you need to show us the code for `useTwoFieldToGetSecondGroup` to see how it turns out to the said result. quite possibly an update there can fix your result

Comment: I add code for useTwoFieldToGetSecondGroup

Comment: that cannot result in `"A":{
     "Y":5,
     "Z":3
  },`, make sure your question is correct in data.

Comment: i modified my question